# "Gmail has stopped" dialog

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, gmail, samsung-galaxy-s-4, crashes

On my Samsung Galaxy S4 with Android 4.4.2, I get constantly a dialog saying "Gmail has stopped" (In french, actually : "Gmail s'est arrêté"). When I click OK, the message re-opens within less than a second.

I tried to restart my device, to no avail. I still get the message.

Anyone knows a solution?

Edit: just an update on how things started: I wanted to kill a bunch of tasks and ran Advanced Task Killer. I probably left Gmail selected and so killed it with the tasks I wanted to get rid of. And all hell broke lose...

Comment: I almost sure I killed Gmail with Advanced Task Killer before, and I never had such a problem. It seems Gmail is more fragile now than it was for some time. So be careful when you kill tasks...

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... An update for Gmail was waiting on Play. I installed it and everything works fine, now. Did I need the update to make it work properly (after an update on Google's servers, or after the last update of my system, for example), or was the update a convenient way to restart Gmail properly? I don't know.

Comment: It's possible that killing Gmail in the first place corrupted one of its data files, which prevented it starting subsequently. The update could have triggered it to check or update its data (e.g. to a newer format), resolving the problem. This is just speculation, though: only someone familiar with the internals of the app would be able to say for sure.

Comment: That's another (and more credible) possibility...